# How to change particular cell color in ios swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an String array like [1,2,3,4,5]. I am displaying this array in tableview. My Question is If I want to change the color of 3rd cell only, How can I compare 3rd element with array in ios swift?

Comment: you want to change the 3rd cell or condition matched  of 3

Comment: condition matched of 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your tableview delegate method based on the condition change the color what you want

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row == 2 ? .red : yellow //or use cell.contentView.backgroundColor = = indexPath.row == 2 ? .red : yellow
}
```

if you want to change the array contains 3 condition based then use like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
cell.backgroundColor = yourArrayName[indexPath.row] == "3" ? .red : yellow //or use cell.contentView.backgroundColor = = yourArrayName[indexPath.row] == "3" ? .red : yellow
}
```

okay we go with alternate way

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
  if let index = yourArrayName.index(of: "3") {
   cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row == index ? .red : yellow 
  }
}
```

Comment: Its working Fine. I accepted your answer also. Thank you

Comment: Karthik : I have phone numbers array, I am comparing this array with my device contacts.My Problem is, my array contains only 10 digits for each element but my device contacts saved with +91 also. like 9848022338 == +919848022338.  So The above code is not working.

Comment: How can I trim +91?

Comment: @ios6457468234 - I updated the answer check once bro

Answer (score 2):

You can check the condition inside your cellforrow function like this too :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCellIndentifier", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCell

        if indexPath.row == 2{
            // Do your modification on the 3rd cell item
            cell.backgroundColor = .red
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: you are compare with indexpath.row. But I need to compare with element

Comment: maybe this is my mistake for your question because you mentioned that you want to change the color of the 3rd cell only, so next time you should specify more clearer than this

Answer (score 0):

I just applied condition under `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextFieldInTableViewCell") as! myProfieTabelViewCellTableViewCell
    if indexPath[1] % 2  == 0{
         cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9088078997, green: 0.9088078997, blue: 0.9088078997, alpha: 1)
        print(indexPath[1])
    }
    else{
         cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}
```